# Creating live CD from already running RHEL 7.7

Tags: linux, rhel7

I'm looking in way to convert already prepared RHEL 7.7 installed on VMware to a LiveCD.

Basically the current installed OS have all ISO and Tools needed for some specific action, and it would be great help if I could just convert it to an ISO and boot it from network ( PXE ) or from a CD.

I have tried Linux Live Kit: https://github.com/Tomas-M/linux-live. Although it finished OK, the resultant ISO is stuck on boot, where it just offer the boot menu and if I click on the boot linux it just start count down over and over..

Is there some easy tool to convert an installed OS to a live CD?

Comment: livemedia-creator ? http://weldr.io/lorax/livemedia-creator.html → lorax. ( Option --make-ostree-live )

Comment: @KnudLarsen that looks interesting... from the docs, if I understand correctly it will take in iso image ( I suppose redhat-server-7.7.iso for example ) and do installation of it into specific folder, than repack it onto live cd iso, or even pxe bootable config ( which is perfect for me ) .. the last thing I need is to stop it after first part and go "into" the installed OS and do modifications, install rps, setup post boot script etc... would a chroot just work for that ?

Comment: lorax documentation EL7 https://weldr.io/lorax/lorax-composer/ ... Ref. https://weldr.io/lorax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

livemedia-creator is the tool I ended up using. Still the final squashed image is about 740MB and I can't seems to make it any smaller... will have to do.